# JSF + https header getting changed to http

Tags: apache, jsf, weblogic

My website is built using JSF. It is running on weblogic app server and is sitting behind an apache webserver.The website is a https site.

When I click on home link on the menu , https is getting changed to http and the below error message is being displayed -

> ## Bad Request
>
> Your browser sent a request that this server
>   could not understand.
>  Reason: You're speaking plain HTTP to an
>   SSL-enabled server port.
>  Instead use the HTTPS scheme to access
>   this URL, please.

I am using the below code in my xhtml -

```
<h:outputLink value="#{menuBean.homeLink}">
    <f:verbatim>Home</f:verbatim>
</h:outputLink>
```

In my backing bean this is the code that I have for homelink -

```
public static final String CONTEXT_PATH = JSFUtil.getRequest().getContextPath();
private String homeLink = CONTEXT_PATH;
     // getters and setters
```

JSF Util has the below snippet -

```
FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
return ((HttpServletRequest) fc.getExternalContext().getRequest());
```

However the other links in menu are working fine (https header is being retained). They are all defined as

```
CONTEXT_PATH\<some path>
```

I am also noticing this issue wherever attribute "redirect" is set as true in faces-config.xml.

Comment: Is there any proxy, redirect, etc, in your Apache that might be interfering in your requests?

Comment: Hi Viccari - Thanks. I have posted the resolution. I too thought it might be apache which might be causing the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding WL front end host and port in weblogic admin console makes WL use the URL specified during redirects. It was a weblogic config issue.